# Injecting dependencies into a plain old Tomcat HTTP servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, dependency-injection

Having become very comfortable with dependency injection as a style, I've found myself writing an HTTP servlet something like this:

```
public class FooServlet extends HttpServlet {

private Dependency dependency;

public void setDependency(Dependency dependency) {
    this.dependency = dependency;
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ...
        Result r = dependency.doSomething(...);
        ...
}
```

This is beautifully easy to unit test, and I'm keen to keep the model -- but now that I come to deploy it in Tomcat, I come to realised that I don't know where I can invoke setDependency() from.

Some vague possibilities that come to mind:

- Get servlet parameters in init(). These are just String, so I'd have to do some Reflection to create. This wouldn't be true DI; just configured dependency creation.
- Something with JNDI
- Somehow, from the Java program in which Tomcat is embedded, get Tomcat to give me a reference to the Servlet object, allowing me to call its setter.
- Use Spring. If I use Spring, I'd be looking for ways to keep it lightweight. This app is not complex enough to warrant Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to Aaron and Filipe, I found what seems to be the most lightweight use of Spring.

Configure a Dispatching servlet in WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>
                    myDispatcher
            </servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/myDispatcher-context.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
    </servlet>
```

In WEB-INF/spring/myDispatcher-context.xml, configure the application context explicitly, so that BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping maps requests to your handling class, and your dependency is injected.

```
    <bean id="/*" class="org.me.MyHandler">
        <property name="dependency" ref="dependency"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dependency" class="org.me.myDependency"/>
```

Write MyHandler as an implementation of `HttpRequestHandler` - it's very much analogous to a Servlet.

This gives you dependency injection. It avoids classpath scanning, and does not load dozens of classes -- but if you want to adopt the more advanced Spring MVC features later, the opportunity is there.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Spring, as it provides a large ecosystem of features and functionalities that could be used by your project to enhance it. But only if you'd really use them. There's no point in loading such a huge framework only to use one little feature in one single place.

That said, you should also take care as the `doPost()` method will be called by different threads, while your `dependency` object is a member variable. This would make your code thread-unsafe, as the same `dependency` instance could be simultaneously used by different threads if it were a singleton.

Comment: Thanks. The issue about thread safety is no different to what you should consider with a network of Spring beans, right?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually just two lines of code to make `@Autowire` work in a servlet:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext( getServletContext() );
appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean( this );
```

There is a drawback, though: Servlets are singletons and they aren't created by Spring, so you can't inject prototype beans. So this will work as long as all injected beans are singletons. When you add a prototype bean later, the code will start to fail with odd errors.

For this reason, I usually create handler beans (see `HttpRequestHandler`) and create them in `doPost()` instead of autowiring the servlet itself.